# How to sort an array of string in descending order by the number of vowels each string has

Tags: java

How should I sort individual strings in descending order. For example if I enter the the size of the array 3 and enter the strings "hello", "rip hi", "AEIOU" I should get "AEIOU", "rip hi","hello" as return after sorting.

This is how far I have come:

```
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n;
        System.out.print("Enter the amount of words you wanna input: ");
        n=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        
        String[] list=new String[n];
        String[] list2=new String[n];
        /// this loop will take input of strings 
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            input.nextLine(); // I don't know why but my first iteration's scanner was being skipped that is why 
                              // I used another input.nextLine pls don't cut marks 
            System.out.print("Enter the "+(i+1)+" word: ");
            list[i]=input.nextLine();
        }
        /// this loop will sort the array by taking individual strings and breaking them in char array and counting how many times
        /// a vowel is present but how to sort ?
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                String temp= list[i];
                char[] ar = temp.toCharArray();
                for (int j = 0; j < ar.length; j++) {
                    int count=0;
                    int count2;
                    if(ar[j] == 'a'|| ar[j] == 'e'|| ar[j] == 'i' || ar[j] == 'o' ||ar[j] == 'u'|| ar[j] == 'A' || ar[j] == 'E' || ar[j] == 'I' || ar[j] == 'O' ||ar[j] == 'U'){
                        count ++;
                    }
                    if(count>0 && count>count2){
                        String temp1=String.copyValueOf(ar);
                    }
                    else{
                        
                    }
                }
             
            }
        /// this loop would show the sorted array
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(""+list[i]);
        }
```

Comment: You need to write a custom `Comparator`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom comparator like this:

> ```
> class SortByNumberOfVowels implements Comparator<String>
> {
>     @Override
>     public int compare ( String o1, String o2 ) {
>         return numOfVowels(o2) - numOfVowels(o1) ;
>     }
>
>     private int numOfVowels ( String o1 ) {
>         int ctr = 0;
>         for(int i = 0;i<o1.length ();i++) {
>             if("AEIOUaeiou".indexOf(o1.charAt ( i )) != -1)
>                 ctr++;
>         }
>         return ctr;
>     }
> }
>
> public class hello {
>
>     public static void main ( String[] args ) {
>         List<String> list = new ArrayList<> (  );
>         list.add("eaiou");list.add("hello");list.add("aaaaaaaaaaaaa");
>         Collections.sort(list, new SortByNumberOfVowels());
>         System.out.println(list);
>     }
> }
> ```

Time complexity will be **nlog(n)*|s|** where **n** = size of list and **|s|** is the average length of strings.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the most efficient way but it will give you the output.

1.Store the value of count and index of the strings in list (i) in a HashMap. HashMap(count, i)

2.Sort the keys of the HashMap. One way to do it is using Collections.sort()

```
  ArrayList<String> keys =  new ArrayList<String>(hash_map.keySet()); 
        Collections.sort(keys);
```

3.Iterate through keys and print the value for each.

```
 for (String s : keys)  
        System.out.println(hash_map.get(s));
```

Comment: HashMap in Java don't allow repetition of keys, and here for keys you are using number of vowels.

This won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As Kayaman said in the comment, probably the best approach will be to implement a dedicated `Comparator` for this task and use it to sort the array.
It could look something like this:

```
public class StringVowelCountComparator implements Comparator<String> {  
    @Override
    public int compare(String first, String second) {
       return (countVowels(first) - countVowels(second));
    }

    private int countVowels(String string){
       int count = 0;
       char[] chars = string.toCharArray();
       for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
          if(ar[i] == 'a'|| ar[i] == 'e'|| ar[i] == 'i' || ar[i] == 'o' ||ar[i] == 'u'|| ar[i] == 'A' || ar[i] == 'E' || ar[i] == 'I' || ar[i] == 'O' ||ar[i] == 'U'){
             count ++;
          }
       }
       return count;        
    }
}
```

And then in your code you just call it like this:

```
Arrays.sort(list, new StringVowelCountComparator());
```

Comment: Thank you all for your replies but I just wanted to know if there's any other way of doing this other than using hashmaps or comparators? I again thank you for your input but I am looking for more very level one way of solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem in your annotate**

`n=input.nextInt();` just read a int but not discard the other world in the line。

I change your code and it works well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n;
    System.out.print("Enter the amount of words you wanna input: \n");
    n = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();

    String[] list = new String[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter the " + (i + 1) + " word: ");
        String inputContent = input.nextLine();
        list[i] = inputContent;
    }
    String[] sorted = new String[3];
    Arrays.stream(list).sorted((o1, o2) -> vowels(o2) - vowels(o1)).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(sorted);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        System.out.println("" + sorted[i]);
    }
}
```

extract a method to number vowels of input string:

```
private static int vowels(String input) {
    String vowels = "AEIOUaeiou";
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    int count = 0;
    for (char ch : chars) {
        if (vowels.contains(ch + "")) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: bro, you are a lifesaver but could you explain me:

Arrays.stream(list).sorted((o1, o2) -> vowels(o2) - vowels(o1)).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(sorted); 

This line cause I got the method as it is nothing but a counter, but what is o1 and o2 stuff

Comment: when we sort array,the most basic thing is compare two elements in the array.when use java stream API,o1 and o2 is elements in stream we execute compare operation.Java Stream API support many method to help us process data，you can find document from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html)